# Problems with dismiss keyboard notification trigging animation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

I have a placeholder that I am animating when the keyboard is opened and closed. So far when the keyboard is opened it animates properly, however when it is closed it stays in place. Below is the code I am using.

```
func setupKeyboardObservers() {

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
```

Setting up the keyboard notifications

```
        let isKeyboardShowing = notification.name == NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow
        let isKeybobardNotShowing = notification.name == NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide
```

Here's where the animations happens

```
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if isKeyboardShowing {

                NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.placeholder, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.searchBarView, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 5).isActive = true
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }, completion: { (completed) in

                })

            }
        }


        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if isKeybobardNotShowing {

                NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.placeholder, attribute: .centerX , relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.searchBarView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }, completion: { (completed) in

                })

            }
        }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use below library, it works fine
https://github.com/totocaster/Typist

Comment: Call self.view.layoutIfNeeded() before you start animation one more time. That is call this method two times in every animation and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Try this. add self.view.layoutIfNeeded() one more time on top your two dispatchqueue...

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
         ....
         self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

Comment: On top of both dispatchqueues?